# Java HTTP Post Multipart

Tags: java, http, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send an HTTP Post Multipart request to a local server in JAVA. I'm trying to send the following:

```
{
 "content-disposition": "form-data; name=\"metadata\"",
"content-type": "application/x-dmas+json",
 "body":         JSON.stringify(client_req)
},
{
"content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\"" + file + "\"; name=\"file\"",
"content-type": "application/octet-stream",
 "body":         [file content]
}
```

I've looked into Apache HTTP components, but it doesn't let me specify the content-type and disposition for each part. Here's what I've written in JAVA using the Apache HTTP API:

`CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

```
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("IP");

        FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(args[0]), "application/octet-stream");
        StringBody hash = new StringBody("{\"hash\": \"\", \"policy\": {\"retention_permitted\": true, \"distribution\": \"global\"}}", ContentType.create("application/x-dmas+json"));

        HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addPart("metadata", hash)
                .addPart("file", bin)
                .build();


        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

`

Comment: That is not Java but JavaScript. Show us the relevant Java code.

Comment: Nonetheless, I'd like to be able to set the content-type and content-disposition for each part in JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor parameters and methods of FilePart and StringPart, with which you compose a Part[] that makes up the multipart request provide this information.

Comment: Will that work with MultipartEntityBuilder? I've seen it used with the deprecated MultipartRequestEntity.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is too late but as reference for anyone looking the answer for the same question, there is several methods in the [MultipartEntityBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html) class that allow you to set the  content-type and content-disposition for each part. For example,

> - addBinaryBody(String name, File file, ContentType contentType, String    filename)
> - addTextBody(String name, String text, ContentType contentType)

If we use the above methods in your example,

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost("http://url-to-post/");

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
String jsonStr = "{\"hash\": \"\", \"policy\": {\"retention_permitted\": true, \"distribution\": \"global\"}}";
builder.addTextBody("metadata", jsonStr, ContentType.create("application/x-dmas+json"));
builder.addBinaryBody("file", new File("/path/to/file"),
    ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "filename");

HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
uploadFile.setEntity(multipart);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
```